# Style PHP code WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, styles

How do I make the following output in white text? span? div?

```
<?php global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  echo 'Welcome, ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`echo 'Welcome,<span class="white-text">' . $current_user->user_firstname . "</span>\n";`

css

```
.white-text{
 color:white;
}
```

you can either use span and div.